# Command not found: pub, when dart is already in path (macOS)

Tags: dart

Getting this error when running `pub get`

`zsh: command not found: pub`

However, I've already added dart to my path with this line:

`export PATH=/usr/lib/dart/bin:$PATH`

Anyone run into anything similar? Would love to figure out what's going on so I can get started on Exercism's Dart exercises.

Comment: Possibilities: A. You didn't update the value of `PATH` in the shell where you tried to run `pub`. B. `/usr/lib/dart/bin` is the wrong path.  C. `pub` isn't executable. Verify that `echo $PATH` prints what you expect and that `ls -l /usr/lib/dart/bin/pub` shows that `pub` exists and has execute permissions.

Comment: Ah, looks like that pub doesn't exist (```No such file or directory```). Would you recommend re-downloading Dart?

Comment: Yes.  The Dart SDK should come with the `bin/pub` binary.